# Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS including subdomains

Tags: apache-http-server, https, redirection, cpanel, htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all `HTTP` traffic to `HTTPS` including subdomains. I have the domain setup with FastComet on their Shared Hosting using cPanel. Some examples of how I like to redirect.

```
http://www.example.com      ->     https://www.example.com
http://example.com          ->     https://example.com
http://www.example.com/mail ->     https://www.example.com/mail
http://example.com/mail     ->     https://example.com/mail
http://mail.example.com     ->     https://mail.example.com
```

I've tried adding below to my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And the more general

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But none of them redirects `http://mail.example.com` to `https://mail.example.com` while redirecting `http://example.com/mail` to `https://example.com/mail` works. What is it I'm missing my setup?

Comment: Where did you place that htaccess file? if it's located in the root of example.com it will only redirect for that domain. You'd have to place a separate file on mail.example.com. If you want such a general redirect it's usually the best to include it in your server configuration rather than htaccess file.

Comment: Currently I have it in the `public_html` folder. The `public_html` folder is in the `root`. Where do I find the server configuration?

Comment: If you're on shared hosting, it's unlikely that you will be able to access it directly. It's usually somewhere in `/etc`. You'd need to change the VirtualHost (likely) see also: [http to https apache redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection). If you're not able to do that, you will have to use a htaccess file for every domain.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a reasonably recent Apache. This ability can be achieved in `extra/http-vhosts.conf`. But *your* ability to accomplish the following in `.htaccess` will be *completely* dependent on your hosting providers willingness to let you do so.

If you place the following in the `.htaccess` file at the root of your server(s). It should accomplish your goal:

```
ServerName MyServer.COM
Redirect permanent / https://myserver.com/
```

All this does is send a `301 permanent`. So you won't get penalized by google (if you care), and browser bookmarks, and other clients will become cluefull of the change.

It's pretty simple to understand. So I won't elaborate further.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to change just copy and paste.

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```